# Динамическое подставление полей в представлениях

Tags: sql

Здравствуйте!
Вопрос такой: Можно ли в sql представлениях динамически подставлять поля?
например есть поля --> [en], [ru] соответствующей таблицы допустим T_Status.
есть таблица T_CurrentLanguge в которой стоит либо [en] либо [ru].
мне надо вытащить в представлении поле из таблицы T_Status которое указанно в таблице T_CurrentLanguge.
Можно зделать всё это по ключу тоесть поле одно но есть ID соответствующего языка, но мне интересно есть ли возможность токого варианта который я указал с полями?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [оператор CASE](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_case_statement.html)

Comment: да я об этом тоже задумовался но вот насоздавал эти CASE а тут раз и новый язык надо добавить получается все запросы перелапатить заново надо (((

Comment: Ну, у вас при добавлении нового языка и столбец придется в таблицу добавлять. Может тогда изменить структуру, чтобы добавление языка приводило к добавлению строки, а не столбца.
Тогда и код менять не придется.

Comment: ну впринцепи я так и решил, просто более наглядно смотрится, ну вообщем так и сделаю... 
Спасибо!